# How to change maven home directory?

Tags: maven, installation

I have maven home directory as below,

```
 [root@localhost configuration-simple]# su -c "vi /etc/profile.d/maven.sh"
 [root@localhost configuration-simple]# mvn -version
 Apache Maven 3.0.5 (r01de14724cdef164cd33c7c8c2fe155faf9602da; 2013-02-19 19:21:28+0530)
  Maven home: /home/kartyk/NetBeansProjects/motown.io/motown-develop/apache-maven-3.0.5
  Java version: 1.7.0_51, vendor: Oracle Corporation
  Java home: /usr/java/jdk1.7.0_51/jre
  Default locale: en_US, platform encoding: UTF-8
  OS name: "linux", version: "3.19.8-100.fc20.x86_64", arch: "amd64",  family: "unix"
[root@localhost configuration-simple]#
```

Now I want to change the Maven home directory to some other folder, how could I do this through command prompt?

Comment: The maven home directory tells you where maven is installed. Is your question how to use another maven installation?

Comment: yes I want to use another maven installation to another directory.

Comment: are you familiar with basic aspects of your OS?

Comment: Well, just unzip/untar the Maven binary distribution in a directory of your choice and then use that version.

Answer (score 2):

I assume you are familiar with basics of your OS.

1. go to [Maven download page](http://maven.apache.org/download.cgi) and get the latest version
2. extract it in a directory of your choice (`/opt` or `/usr/local` or ...)
3. set and export the environment variable MAVEN_HOME in your `.bashrc`
4. extend and export the environment variable PATH by $MAVEN_HOME/bin